# Visual Studio Team Services (TFS online) - Get latest over two PCs with same account (VS2015)

Tags: visual-studio, version-control, visual-studio-2015, azure-devops

My issue is that Get Latest (TFS) does not work using the same account over two PC's for a newly created file.  Steps to reproduce:

On my main PC I opened Visual Studio 2015 (CE).

I created a new typescript (.ts) file.

I checked this new ts file in.

I go to work on my laptop and open VS2015 (using my same Microsoft Live account) and the new files do not download when I go to Get Latest.

If I traverse the files to see what was checked in on the server, they have been checked in successfully.

Exploring the files via VS2015 through the team explorer I see the files, they are indicated as not having downloaded and also is indicate "latest" as "no".

It would seem that my laptop is telling VS online that no changes to this file have been made (well in fact I cannot download the file to my laptop and is not present on my laptop so technically true - its hasn't changed because I can't download it to change it).

**How do I tell VS online that my laptop is not my main pc while still using the same account to login?  Or am I missing something?  I've not used TFS an awful lot.**

I'm fully updated. I did some folder re-naming so possible it's a bug to do with that.

Comment: Did you try right-clicking on the file and select "Advanced-> Get Specific Version" with "Overwrite writeable files that are not checked out" and "Overwrite all files even if the local version matches the specified version" checked?

Answer (score 0):

I can not reproduce this issue via the steps you provided. The file can be downloaded successfully on both PC with same account. Since you mentioned that you did some folder renaming, so you need to check if your local workspace mapping is still correct. An quick way to fix this is creating a new workspace for the project. This will get all the latest files on Version Control.

There are several ways to get the latest version:

1. Get the latest version from "Solution Explorer" by :right click on the project/solution file -> source control -> get latest version. This only updates all the files related to the project/solution to the latest version. For example, you have ProjectA and ProjectB in the solution, and you right click on ProjectA to get the latest version, the files listed under ProjectA in solution explorer will be updated/downloaded. Other files won't be updated.
2. Get the latest version from "Source Control Explorer" by :right click on the folder -> Get latest version. This will update all the files under the folder.

Comment: I created a new workspace on laptop (saving to a new folder), created some new files on laptop and when I chose get latest on my main pc, it didn't fetch the new typescript files I had created.  I had to manually traverse to the files in team explorer click them and get latest.  Then I had to do a get specific version and check the overwrite buttons.  This is still a fuss just to get latest version.

Comment: @DanAbdn How do you get the latest version generally? Right click on the solution and select “Get Latest Version"? If yes, are those new added files placed in the solution folder or been added to the solution?

Comment: I right click the project file > source control > get latest version (recursive).  So Solution > src > PROJECTNAME [right click on this].  Just like would have done in Visual Source Safe really.  File created from laptop doesn't exist on main pc, so I explore and get latest on that one file that seems to then download the file.

Comment: @DanAbdn I added some clarification about the get latest version feature in my answer. According to your action, you are get the latest version for project. So you need to make sure the new added files are been added to the project (Listed under the project in solution explorer). Otherwise, you need to go to Source Control Explorer and right click on the project folder to get all the files to latest version.